# Use an alias on Pig UDF paramter

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need your help to know how to use an alias (stored tuple) on my Pig udf function, i exmplain:

my_file.csv

```
101,message here
102,message here
103,message here
...
```

My script PIG:

```
X = load'mydata.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (myVar:chararray);
A = load'my_file.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (key:chararray,value:chararray);
B = GROUP par ALL;
C = foreach B {
    D = ORDER par BY key;
    GENERATE BagToTuple(D);
};
```

`the result of the   C   is something like (101,message here, 102, message here, 103, message here...)`

Now what i need is to pass this result in my udf function like :

```
Z = foreach X generate MYUDF(myVar, C);
```

the alias "C" is the tuple key,value,key,value...

MYUDF :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.PigWarning;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

public class ReDecode extends EvalFunc<String> {
    int numParams = -1;
    Pattern mPattern = null;
    @Override
    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        try {
            return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(getSchemaName(this
                    .getClass().getName().toLowerCase(), input),
                    DataType.CHARARRAY));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
@Override
    public String exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
        if (numParams==-1)  // Not initialized
        {
            numParams = tuple.size();
            if (numParams <= 2) {
                String msg = "Decode: Atleast an expression and default string is required.";
                throw new IOException(msg);
            }
            if (tuple.size()%2!=0) {
                String msg = "ItssPigUDFs.ReDecode : Some parameters are unmatched.";
                throw new IOException(msg);
            }
        }

        if (tuple.get(0)==null)
            return null;

        try {
            for (int count = 1; count < numParams - 1; count += 2)
            {

                mPattern=Pattern.compile((String)tuple.get(count));
                if (mPattern.matcher((String)tuple.get(0)).matches())
                {
                    return (String)tuple.get(count+1);
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            warn("ItssPigUDFs.ReDecode : Data type error", PigWarning.UDF_WARNING_1);
            return null;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            String msg = "ItssPigUDFs.ReDecode : Encounter null in the input";
            throw new IOException(msg);
        }

        return (String)tuple.get(tuple.size()-1);
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why can't your UDF accept a Tuple as a parameter? It shouldn't matter what you name it on the Pig side

Comment: I don't understand your point, can you please explain it to me?

Comment: You have to write `MYUDF` in some language, let's say Java. Just like writing a method in any other language, the parameter name can be completely different than the value passed in to it, i.e. it shouldn't matter that you use an alias.

Comment: the alias which i talk about contains a result of a pig query (i.e. A = foreach var generate totuple(something); ) so i need to use the content of A in my udf + a variable to do some matching, I already have a java udf function.

Comment: I'msorry maybe i used the word 'alias' in the wrong place, but what i need is to use an expression already stored before in my pig script and use it such as a tuple for my pig udf

Comment: Yes, that is called an alias. I still don't understand your problem. Can you add your UDF code? Have you done this in your UDF -- `import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple `? Then do you have a method like `public String exec(??? param1, Tuple param2) `?

Comment: Yes sure, i have an udf function and it works with no problem when i put variables manually in my pig script ( myudf(index, 'key', 'value', 'key2', 'value2'...) the function do some matching between the index and the key and return the value, but what i need now is to enter a file which contains the key,value .. so i need something like   myudf(index, THEFILEOFPARAMS)

Comment: Can you please [add to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34046286/edit) (not the comments) the full Java code of your UDF up to the `exec` method definition?

Comment: You can find the code of my udf now, thnak you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `numParams` is needed; the number of params that you get to the UDF will be `input.size()`.

Therefore, if you call `MYUDF(myVar, C)`, then you should be able to get those values in Java like `String myVar = (String) input.get(0)` and `Tuple param2 = input.get(1)`.